# Prove $\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) + \vec b \times (\vec c \times \vec a) + \vec c \times (\vec a \times \vec b) = \vec0$

Tags: vectors, tensors

My task is to prove the following vector identity using Einstein notation:
$$\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) + \vec b \times (\vec c \times \vec a) + \vec c \times (\vec a \times \vec b) = \vec0$$

This is my attempt:

$$\varepsilon^i_{\ jk}a^j\varepsilon^k_{\ lm}b^lc^m + \varepsilon^i_{\ jk}b^j\varepsilon^k_{\ lm}c^la^m + \varepsilon^i_{\ jk}c^j\varepsilon^k_{\ lm}a^lb^m = \varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon_{klm}a_jb^lc^m + \varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon_{klm}b_jc^la^m + \varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon_{klm}c_ja^lb^m = 
\varepsilon^{kij}\varepsilon_{klm}a_jb^lc^m + \varepsilon^{kij}\varepsilon_{klm}b_jc^la^m + \varepsilon^{kij}\varepsilon_{klm}c_ja^lb^m =
[\delta_i^l\delta_j^m - \delta_i^m\delta_j^l]a_jb^lc^m + 
[\delta_i^l\delta_j^m - \delta_i^m\delta_j^l]b_jc^la^m + 
[\delta_i^l\delta_j^m - \delta_i^m\delta_j^l]c_ja^lb^m = 
a_jb^ic^j - a_jb^jc^i + b_jc^ia^j - b_jc^ja^i+c_ja^ib^j-c_ja^jb^i
$$

I am stuck here and unable to move forward. What can I do now according to the rules of the notation?

Comment: By the way this is known as the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity). For a proof see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vector_Cross_Product_satisfies_Jacobi_Identity)

Comment: It is an easy proof. I just need to do it using Einstein notation to get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the einstein summation convention. In you last expression the first term has an individual b, and a summation over a and c. This is the same in the last term. Only difference is which is upper or which is a lower index. Just use the metric tensor and you see they are equal. Analogously for the rest.

So 1st and 6th will cancel, 2 and 3, 4 and 5.